# make users update to chrome web store hosted extension from one which is not hosted on web store

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a version of extension both in Chrome web store and one distributed by other means, the latter has a different id from the one from web store. I have users using that not-from-webstore extension. Is there a way to make users update to a web store based extension? 'update_url' : 'http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx' is not working. Maybe there is some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to automatically update an existing extension with one ID to another extension with a different ID. If you had maintained the same ID, non Web Store users would automatically update to the CWS version.

The best idea is to update the old extension that prompts users to install the new version and remove the old version.